# How can I get the coordinates of these points?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I've written a python script that detects tracking points in an image:

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2

image = cv2.imread("image.jpg")

# MAGIC!

cv2.imshow("Image", image)
cv2.imshow("Tracking points", mask)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

This is the result:
[image: Before]

[image: After]

How can I get the coordinates of the white dots?

Comment: Find the 255 points in the sea of 0s. Your mat array will be mostly 0s. The high values are the white values. Find the places in the array that are high values and that will give you the white dots. Discard white pixels too close to other white pixels until you get points for all 6 dots. np.where might help.

Comment: Try [connectedComponentsWithStats](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga107a78bf7cd25dec05fb4dfc5c9e765f), find the centroids of dots.

Comment: @Rotem thank you, this worked!